# linking from one page to another on coresponding id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 php pages with my database table `products` with columns: `productid`, `name`, `price`, `about`,`city`.

On the 1st page (list.php) i display all products with only `name` with a while loop:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN orase
ON anunturi_firme.Oras = orase.id
JOIN domenii
ON anunturi_firme.Domeniu = domenii.id"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<table id="anunt">
<tr>
    <td class="left">
    <?php echo '<a href="" style="color: blue">'.$row['name'].'</a><br>'; ?>
    </td>       
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
?>
```

I want to link each product to a 2nd page named *details.php* with all details about products. So I wish to display the price, city, and about from my table from database. I am little begginer in this, I guess it has to be something with id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first page, you should update the link by adding an id to it (you guessed right) and a reference to the new page containing the details :

```
<?php echo '<a href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'" style="color: blue">'.$row['name'].'</a><br>'; ?>
```

On the new page details.php, you can get the requested id by using :

```
<?php $product_id = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

This gets the id parameter from the url. Then you can query the database for the particular id and retrieve the details.

```
<?php $new_query = "SELECT ... WHERE id = ".$product_id; ?>
```

Comment: it works but if I log in on my website and I want to see details page it displays undefined index errors to my variables :(

Comment: Try to figure out which ones are undefined and why. Use <?php echo $variable_name; ?> for that. Then correct the code. Post another question if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="details.php?price=<?php echo $row['price']?>&city=<?php echo $row['city']?>&about=<?php echo $row['about']?>" style="color: blue"><?php echo $row['name']?></a>
```

i am assuming that price ,city and about are coming in $row array

Answer (score 0):

**In the first page (list.php)**

You need to pass the `productid` of the record from the first page to the second page and there run a `SELECT` query using the `productid`

```
<?php echo '<a href="details.php?productid='.$row['productid'].'" style="color: blue">'.$row['name'].'</a><br>'; ?>
```

---

**In the second page (details.php)**

```
$id  = $_REQUEST['productid']

$sql = "SELECT price, city, about FROM products WHERE productid = '$id' "
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. First: In list.php when you query the database grab all detail you need for the second page and place them in hidden inputs. Pass these to session vars and pick them up on the second page.

Second when you query on the first page, grab the I'd, pass the I'd to the second page and build a new query with that I'd.